# Dropdown menu overlapping menus

Tags: css

I have made a website with a navigation menu, there are also two dropdown menus that work fine on the desktop. However, on mobile, the drop-down menu 'recruiting' overlaps other menus once clicked. I also have an issue with the font awesome icon, when I press on one of the menus the other arrow also activates. How do I solve these issues?

```js
var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks")

function showMenu() {
    navLinks.style.right = "0";
}
function hideMenu() {
    navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
}

let click = document.querySelector('.click');

let list = document.querySelector('.Sub-menu-1');




document.getElementById('navLinks').onclick = function () {

    var className = ' ' + navLinks.className + ' ';

    this.className = ~className.indexOf(' active ') ?
        className.replace(' active ', ' ') :
        this.className + ' active';
};
click.addEventListener("click", () => {

    list.classList.toggle('NewSub-menu-1');
    

});

let click2 = document.querySelector('.click2');

let list2 = document.querySelector('.Sub-menu-2');




document.getElementById('navLinks').onclick = function () {

    var className = ' ' + navLinks.className + ' ';

    this.className = ~className.indexOf(' active ') ?
        className.replace(' active ', ' ') :
        this.className + ' active';
};
click2.addEventListener("click", () => {

    list2.classList.toggle('NewSub-menu-2');


});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background:black;
}

.Header {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(Images/Home.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position:relative;
}
nav{
    display:flex;
    padding: 2% 2% 0 2%;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items:center;
}

nav img{
    width:9rem;

}
.banner img {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 8% 0% 0% 0%;
}
.nav-Links {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
}

    .nav-Links ul li {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        position: relative;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20px;
    }


.nav-Links ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-Links ul li::after {
    content: '';
    width: 0%;
    height: 3px;
    background: royalblue;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav-Links ul li:hover::after{
    width:100%;
}

.Header-Text {
    width: 90%;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8% 0% 0% 0%
}
.Header-Text h1{
    font-size:60px;

}

.Header-Text p {
    margin: 10px 0 10px;
    font-size:25px;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
}

.Button{
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    border:1px solid white;
    padding:12px 34px;
    font-size:20px;
    background: transparent;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.Button:hover{
    border: 1px solid royalblue;
    background:royalblue;
    transition: 0.7s;
}

nav .fas{
    display:none;
}

@media(max-width: 700px) {
    .Header-Text h1 {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .nav-Links ul li {
        display: block;
    }

    .nav-Links {
        position: fixed;
        background: royalblue;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 200px;
        top: 0;
        right: -201px;
        text-align: left;
        z-index: 2;
        transition: 1s;
    }

    nav .fas {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        margin: 10px;
        font-size: 22px;
        cursor: pointer
    }

    nav {
        display: flex;
        padding: 2% 1%;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }

        nav img {
            width: 100px;
        }

    .nav-Links ul {
        padding: 20px;
    }

        .nav-Links ul li .Sub-menu-1 ul {
            margin-top: -20px;
        }


    .nav-Links ul {
        padding-right: 0px;
    }

    .row {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

        .row img {
            flex-direction: column;
            margin-top: 5%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            width: 100%;
        }

    .content-table th,
    .content-table td {
        font-size: 10px;
    }


}




.Sub-Header{
    height:50vh;
    width:100%;   
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
}

.Sub-Header h1{
    font-size:50px;
}

.About-Us{
    width:85%;
    margin:auto;
    padding-top:80px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
    
}

.about-col{
    flex-basis:48%;
    padding:30px 2px;
}

.about-col img{
    width:100%;
}

.row {
    margin-top:5%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;  
}


.about-col h1{
    padding-top:0;
}

.About-Col p {
    padding: 15px 0 25px;
    text-align: justify;   
}

.Course{
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:100px;
}

h1{
    font-size:36px;
    font-weight:600;

}

p{
    color:black;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:22px;
    padding:5px 0px 10px 0px;
    text-align:justify;
}

.Blue{
    border:1px solid royalblue;
    background:transparent;
    color:royalblue;
    font-size:20px;
}

.Blue:hover {
    color: white;
}


.content-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 25px 0;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    width:100%;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.content-table thead tr {
    background-color: royalblue;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.content-table th,
.content-table td {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    }

.content-table tbody tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.content-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.content-table tbody tr:last-of-type {
     border-bottom: 2px solid royalblue;
}

.content-table tbody tr.active-row {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: royalblue;
}

.Location{
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    padding:80px 0;
}

.Location iframe{
    width:100%;
}

.Contact-Us{
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
   
}
.Contact-Col {
    flex-basis: 48%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.Contact-Col div{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    margin-bottom:40px;
}

.Contact-Col div .fas, .far{
    font-size: 40px;
    color:royalblue;
    margin:10px;
    margin-right:30px;
}
.Contact-Col div p{
    margin:0;
}

.Contact-Col div h5 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight:400;
}

.Contact-Col input, .Contact-Col textarea{
    width:100%;
    padding:15px;
    margin-bottom:17px;
    outline:none;
    border: 1px solid royalblue;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    color:royalblue;
}

.Sub-menu-1,
.Sub-menu-2 {
    display: none;
}

.NewSub-menu-1,
.NewSub-menu-2 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

    .NewSub-menu-1 ul,
    .NewSub-menu-2 ul {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        transition: 2s;
    }



.nav-Links ul li .Sub-menu-1 ul li,
.nav-Links ul li .Sub-menu-2 ul li {
    width: 110px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

.fas.fa-chevron-left {
    
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.nav-Links.active .fas.fa-chevron-left {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transition:1s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
    <title>324SQN - City of Randwick</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet1.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
</head>
<body>
    <section class="Header">
        
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="Images/Logo.png" /></a>
            <a href="index.html" class="banner"><img src="Images/Sologan.png" /></a>

            <div class="nav-Links" id="navLinks">
                <i class="fas fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>

                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="Home.html">Home</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="About.html">About Us</a> </li>
                    <li class="click2">
                        Recruiting  <span class="fas fa-chevron-left"></span>

                        <div class="Sub-menu-2">

                            <ul>

                                <li><a href="#">Number 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Number 2</a></li>                   

                            </ul>

                        </div>

                    </li>
                    <li> <a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="">Leave Request</a> </li>
                    <li  class="click"> CadetLinks  <span class="fas fa-chevron-left"></span>

                        <div class="Sub-menu-1">

                            <ul>

                                <li><a href="#">Number 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Number 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Number 3</a></li>

                            </ul>

                        </div>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <i class="fas fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
        </nav>
        <div class="Header-Text">
            <h1>Number 324 (City of Randwick) Squadron</h1>
            <p>Educate, Challenge, Excites</p>
            <a href="" class="Button">Click Here To Know More</a>
        </div>
    </section>

   <script src="Script1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see just a black screen

Comment: Is there any text

Comment: There should be a sidebar

Answer (score 0):

Add `z-index-1` to NewSub-menu-1 and NewSub-menu-2

The both icon will be rotated at the same time because of this:

```
.nav-Links.active .fas.fa-chevron-left {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transition:1s;
}
```

Here you add style to each fa-chevron-left which parent has class active. And because it's true for the both icons, the both icons will be rotated.

Comment: Will this make the other menus go down or hide them?

Comment: This will bring dropdown lists forward. If you see in the dev tools, the both lists are existing in the DOM, they are just behind the nav. On desktop they are visible, because nave panel is horizontal and dropdown, well drop down, when open. And in the mobile view you made nav vertical, so it will cover dropdowns.

Comment: Oh ok Thanks, for the icon problem is there easy way to solve it? Or do i need to just add separate ids?

Comment: Instead of adding active to nav-links, you can add it to those dropdown which is currently open.